# Creating a numpy matrix of tuples from 4 one-dimensional arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have four one-dimensional numpy arrays A, B, C, D, and I want to create a matrix M such that each entry M[i, j, k, l] of the matrix is the tuple (a, b, c, d)

where a = A[i], b = B[j], c = C[k] and d = D[d].

How can I go about constructing it efficiently without loops?

Comment: why tuples?  That won't be an efficient array.

Comment: I wanted to do vectorization; but with each entry being decided conditioned on the indexes of an entry -- unsure how to do that so was thinking of using this as an intermediate step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty array `M` with the correct shape (note the 4 in the last dimension -- that's your tuple), and use broadcasting to assign entire rows/columns in `M` afterwards.

```py
M = np.empty((
    len(a), len(b), len(c), len(d), 4
))

M[..., 0] = a[:, None, None, None]
M[..., 1] = b[None, :, None, None]
M[..., 2] = c[None, None, :, None]
M[..., 3] = d[None, None, None, :]
```

Comment: Oh just one additional follow-up question: if I were to apply np.vectorize on this 5D matrix with some function, that will take as input every entry -- is it possible to exclude the fifth dimension so that the function passed into vectorize can take in the 4-element tuple instead?

Comment: `np.vectorize` iterates all the way down to the scalar element level.  It has a `signature` parameter that probably could do what you want, but that's even slower.

Comment: `np.vectorize` does broadcasting for you.  If your function is `fn(a,b,c,d)`, the vectorized version could take `ffn(a[:,None,None,None], b[....] etc)` (same expanded arrays as above).  But keep in mind that `np.vectorize` is not a speed tool; just a convenience.

Comment: Ah I see -- is there an alternative to this? I tried ```np.apply_along_axis```, it is also slow.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is also an iterative function - iterating on all dimensions except the last.  If your function only works with 1d arrays, then it has to be called once for each 1d array in the larger one (plus a trial call to determine output type/shape).  It's calling that function 1000s of times that's slow, not the iteration mechanism itself.